# Tool that can tell what handler functions are bind on which events with a given element?

Tags: javascript

Do you know is there any software that can tell what handler functions are bind on which events with a given element on the page, probably works like 'Inspect Element' on Firefox.

Thx in advance.

Answer (score 3):

There is a feature for this in latest builds of Webkit, in the Developer tools.

I don't know if it's available in any stable builds yet, but I'd suggest downloading latest Safari or Chrome, and if it's not there, then get a Webkit nightly from http://nightly.webkit.org

Comment: There is FireQuery that works only for jQuery bound events (essentially inspecting the $.data cache) - http://firequery.binaryage.com/